# Nonetype object has no lower attribute

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, sklearn-pandas

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Can anyone help me to figure out how to solve this error!?

Searched many times but seems like nothing worked.

```
for feature in features:
  df[feature] = df[feature].replace('-',None)

def combine_features(row):
  try: 
    return row['genre']+ " " + row['star'] +" " + row['name'] +" " +row[' rating'] +" "+ row['director']
  except:
    print ("Error",row)

df["Combined_features"] = df.apply(combine_features,axis = 1)
print("Combined Features",df["Combined_features"].head())

cv = CountVectorizer()
count_matrix = cv.fit_transform(df["Combined_features"])
#here it gives error NoneType object has no attribute 'lower'

cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(count_matrix)
movie_user_likes = "Avatar"
```

Comment: Verify if your `combined_features` has any `nan` values and replace/delete them.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [52]: None.lower()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-52-bdce891aab80>", line 1, in <module>
    None.lower()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

`cv.fit_transform(df["Combined_features"])` evidently this `fit` expects string values that can be cast to lower case (thus ignoring upper/lower distinction).  And that `df` column/Series must have more than strings, with at least one `None` element.  It's your responsibility to ensure the data provided to `fit` meets its expectations.

When you created that column, did you get any "Error" reports?  That `combine` function will return a `None` in such cases.

Comment: No, there weren't any such error reports while creating this function. This is the error which I'm getting                                                                                 
         `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _preprocess(doc, accent_function, lower)
     66     """
     67     if lower:
---> 68         doc = doc.lower()
     69     if accent_function is not None:
     70         doc = accent_function(doc)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'`  Please help me figure out!

Comment: I see a `print... head`.  Why haven't you shown us that?  Or have you taken time to look at the rest of that column?  The polite thing, when begging for help, is to provide full information.  Don't leave us guessing!  I already told you that, according to the error, there are `None` elements in that frame.  You need to find them!

Comment: I'm really sorry for the inconvenience caused, but I have provided the whole code above.